# Collectionviewcell only showing in one of the tab item

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

I have my storyboard set up such that

Tab bar controller -> nav bar controller 1, nav bar controller 2 -> CollectionView controller 1, CollectionView controller 2

The content inside my collectionviews are basically database i get from firebase (which is working fine). It's just when I start up my app, I can't see the cells in the first collectionview but I can see the cells in my second collectionview. Also, I added a print statement and a segue when you click on a cell and this actually works on both collectionviews. I just can't see the content (just a label) of my collectionviewcell in the first collectionview (the first tab item).

This is the code for my first tab bar item

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SaleListViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
let rootref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
var item_names = [String]()
var item_image_urls = [String]()
var item_details = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var group = DispatchGroup()
var processRunning = false

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.load_data()
}

/**
 Call the firebase function
 */
func load_data(){
    self.group.enter()
    self.processRunning = true
    get_firebase_data(){
        if(self.processRunning){
            self.processRunning = false
            self.group.leave()
        }
    }
    self.group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("done")
    })
}
/**
 Get data from firebase database
 - parameter completionHandler: Function to be called once it's finished
 */
func get_firebase_data(completionHandler: () -> ()){
    rootref.child("Sale").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var item_data = snapshot.value! as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            for(type_2_container,item_list) in item_data{
                for(uid_container, item_detail_container) in item_list as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    for(uid, item_detail) in item_detail_container as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                        var item_detail_dict = item_detail as? Dictionary<String,String>
                        var item_detail_temp = Dictionary<String, String>()
                        for key in (item_detail_dict?.keys)!{
                            item_detail_temp[key] = item_detail_dict?[key]
                        }
                        item_detail_temp["user_id"] = uid
                        self.item_details.append(item_detail_temp)
                        if(!self.item_names.contains(item_detail_dict!["item_name"]!)){
                            self.item_names.append(item_detail_dict!["item_name"]!)
                            self.item_image_urls.append(item_detail_dict!["item_image"]!)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            print(self.item_details)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            print("data was reloaded")
        }
    })
    completionHandler()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.item_details.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:SellcollectViewCellController = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellSale", for: indexPath) as! SellcollectViewCellController
    cell.cell_name_sale.text = self.item_details[indexPath.row]["item_name"]
    print(cell.cell_name_sale.text)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("selected")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetail", sender: self.item_details[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "toDetail"){
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! ShowDetailsViewController
        let item_details = sender as! Dictionary<String, String>
        nextVC.item_details = item_details
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/**
 Signs out a user when the button linked with the IBAction is clicked.
 - parameter sender: Object that sent the action message
 */

@IBAction func log_out(_ sender: Any) {
    do{
        try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logout", sender: nil)
        print("user logged out!")
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

}

And this is my second tab bar item

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class BuyListViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

let rootref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
var item_names = [String]()
var item_image_urls = [String]()
var item_details = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
var group = DispatchGroup()
var processRunning = false

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.load_data()
}



func load_data(){
    self.group.enter()
    self.processRunning = true
    get_firebase_data(){
        if(self.processRunning){
            self.processRunning = false
            self.group.leave()
        }
    }

    self.group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("done")
    })
}

func get_firebase_data(completionHandler: () -> ()){
    rootref.child("Buy").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("inside buy firebase")
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var item_data = snapshot.value! as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            for(type_2_container,item_list) in item_data{
                for(uid_container, item_detail_container) in item_list as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    for(uid, item_detail) in item_detail_container as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                        var item_detail_dict = item_detail as? Dictionary<String,String>
                        var item_detail_temp = Dictionary<String, String>()
                        for key in (item_detail_dict?.keys)!{
                            item_detail_temp[key] = item_detail_dict?[key]
                        }
                        item_detail_temp["user_id"] = uid
                        self.item_details.append(item_detail_temp)
                        if(!self.item_names.contains(item_detail_dict!["item_name"]!)){
                            self.item_names.append(item_detail_dict!["item_name"]!)
                            self.item_image_urls.append(item_detail_dict!["item_image"]!)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            print(self.item_details)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            print("data was reloaded")
        }
    })
    completionHandler()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.item_details.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:BuycollectViewCellController = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellBuy", for: indexPath) as! BuycollectViewCellController
    cell.cell_name_buy.text = self.item_details[indexPath.row]["item_name"]
    print(cell.cell_name_buy.text)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("selected")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetail", sender: self.item_details[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "toDetail"){
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! ShowDetailsViewController
        let item_details = sender as! Dictionary<String, String>
        nextVC.item_details = item_details
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func log_out(_ sender: Any) {
    do{
        try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logout", sender: nil)
        print("user logged out!")
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

}

This is my custom collection view cell controller for the first tab item

```
import UIKit

class SellcollectViewCellController: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell_name_sale: UILabel!

}
```

This is the second collection view cell controller

```
import UIKit

class BuycollectViewCellController: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell_name_buy: UILabel!

}
```

[This is a screenshot of my tab bar controller with the two tab items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XVXX.png)

[Screenshot of the first bar item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE27g.png)

Comment: Do both collectionviews use the same viewcontroller?

Comment: no they dont seperate controllers and also seperate custom cells

Comment: The code is pretty much exactly the same..just different variable names and getting different database from firebase...

Comment: does the label appear somewhat greyed out at all in the sidebar of 'document outline' panel? (the left side panel of the storyboard editor)

Comment: Not at all. Nothing out of the ordinary...

Comment: If you reverse the order of the collectionviews, so that 2 refers to tab 1 and vice versa, does the problem still exist? It might tell us whether it is a viewstack issue or a code issue

Comment: oh let me try that!

Comment: yeap I just tried flipping it and my second view isnt displaying(which was my first view)

Comment: Are you able to include the code for both controllers? I understand if you can't if the code is private

Comment: also if you could add screenshots that would be useful

Comment: So sorry for the late reply :(. I just added all the code and the screenshot of my storyboard. I tripled(actually like 10 times) that my all the views in my storyboard have the correct classes set.

Comment: In your storyboard take each collection view and drag it to the little yellow icon of its own view and set the sourse and do it again for the delegate.

Comment: Those are already set

Comment: oh.. what does `print(self.item_details)` prints?

Comment: It prints my firebase database I just parsed it into a dictionary to a format I want it to be

Comment: so you get all the data of the first query but its doesn't populate it... very strange... maybe you need to set the `reloadData()` in your main queue

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}`

Comment: It populates perfectly fine in my second tab bar item. I just can't upload the screenshot for some reason lol.. I'll try that

Comment: It still isn't working :(

Comment: The first tab is not showing anything but the second tab is showing everything well right? try to print inside the `numberOfItemsInSection ` the count and check if it is ok!

Comment: Yeah the count is fine. If you actually see the code I print "selected" whenever I select my cell. If i actually click on my empty view I can see it print them. Currently my item_details.count is 3 and I am able to click all 3 cells and even segue to the "toDetail" view. It's just the display that is not being set.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the cells... check `CellSale` as the `cell identifier` and also in your cell file to see if the labels are correct assigned to the controller

Comment: The collectioncell identifier is CellSale and my label inside the custom cell class is connected to my UIlabel inside the cell correctly. And also the class is set correctly to the custom cell class